# Adding Progress bar while loading Image list to listbox using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, progress-bar

I am trying to add Images using open file dialog and folder browse dialog and populating the image list to listbox.While adding these Images I need to show the progress bar for every image it loads.

I am trying to get that but when the value of the progress bar say something around 25 0r 40 it is stopping at that point but I need to show the progress bar until it completes the 100% and then populates the Image list.

How do I do that?

Here is my code:

```
    Private Sub AddImages_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles AddImages.Click

    If Not Directory.Exists(Application.StartupPath + "\Backup\") = True Then
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Application.StartupPath + "\Backup\")
    End If



    OpenFileDialog1.FileName = "Select a Image"
    OpenFileDialog1.Multiselect = True
    OpenFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures"
    OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "All Type Of Image Files|*.*|Joint Photographic Experts Group [JPEG]|*.jpg|Bitmap [BMP|*.bmp|Tagged Image File Format [TIFF]|*.tiff|Portable Network Graphics [PNG]|*.png"
    If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then

        ProgressBar2.Show()
        ProgressBar2.Step = 10
        Dim str As String
        For Each str In OpenFileDialog1.FileNames
            Load.Text = "Loading..."

            Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
            Dim MyName As String
            Dim MyExtension As String

            MyName = fso.GetFileName(CStr(str))
            MyExtension = fso.GetExtensionName(MyName)

            System.IO.File.Copy(str, Application.StartupPath + "\Backup\" + MyName & "." & MyExtension, True)

            CheckedListBox1.Items.Add(str, CheckState.Checked)
            Thumbcontrol1.AddThumbnail(str)
            Thumbcontrol1.BackgroundImage = Nothing
            CheckedListBox1.SelectedIndex = 0
            ProgressBar2.PerformStep()
        Next
        SaveProject.Enabled = True
        Delete.Enabled = True
        Edit.Enabled = True
        ClearAll.Enabled = True
        CheckAll.Enabled = True
        UncheckAll.Enabled = True
        Timer1.Stop()
        Load.Text = "Loading Completed"
    Else
    End If
    ProgressBar2.Visible = False
    Load.Text = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't understand. You're increasing the value of `ProgressBar2` by 10 for each file (out of `OpenFileDialog1.FileNames`). How do you know how many files there are? It could be 2 or 20 - you're not checking that.

Comment: Why don't you forget about `Step`, add a counter to your loop (keeping track of how many files have been loaded) and just call `ProgressBar2.Value = (counter * 100) / OpenFileDialog1.FileNames` instead of `PerformStep`

Comment: Yes thats what I am thinking abt actually we dont know how many they can add and When I did its giving me the error as Operator '/' is not defined for types 'Double' and '1-dimensional array of String'.

Comment: My bad, try `ProgressBar2.Value = (counter * 100) / OpenFileDialog1.FileNames.Length` of course.

Comment: `OpenFileDialog1.FileNames` returns you an array of file names your user has selected. Its `Length` property will return you a NUMBER of those file names. You need to divide the number of files you have already loaded by the total number of files.

Comment: It did not work as now it's not even starting the progress bar

Comment: Do you increment your `counter` variable? I posted an updated piece of code as an aswer.

Comment: Yes I have done but no result anyways thanks for helping me.I will try it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `ProgressBar2.Step = 10` line and do this:

```
        Dim str As String
        Dim counter As Integer 'new!
        For Each str In OpenFileDialog1.FileNames
            Load.Text = "Loading..."

            Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
            Dim MyName As String
            Dim MyExtension As String

            MyName = fso.GetFileName(CStr(str))
            MyExtension = fso.GetExtensionName(MyName)

            System.IO.File.Copy(str, Application.StartupPath + "\Backup\" + MyName & "." & MyExtension, True)

            CheckedListBox1.Items.Add(str, CheckState.Checked)
            Thumbcontrol1.AddThumbnail(str)
            Thumbcontrol1.BackgroundImage = Nothing
            counter += 1 'new
            CheckedListBox1.SelectedIndex = 0
            ProgressBar2.Value = (counter * 100) / OpenFileDialog1.FileNames.Length 'new
        Next
```

It does not address the problem of your not using threading, as other answers are correct to point out.

Answer (score 0):

Don´t use the UI for loading. Use Background worker. BackgroundWorker works in another thread, and it can report the progress to bind it to a progressbar.

Answer (score 0):

The progress bar stops moving because Windows thinks there is something seriously wrong with your program.  It replaces your main window with the 'ghost' window, you can tell because it says "Not Responding" in the title bar.

It does this to help alert the user that your program is dead to the world and will not respond to any input from the user.  Clicking the mouse or banging on the keyboard will not have any effect, all the user can do is watch helplessly while your code goes through the motions.

This does not make a desirable user interface.  You solve it by using BackgroundWorker so the heavy lifting is done on a separate thread.  Leaving the user interface thread responsive.  Be sure to read the MSDN article for it so you know what to do, you'll have to adapt your code.